# iTunes Connect error: "An In-App Purchase has been returned"

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, ios9

I'm seeing the following error in `iTunes Connect` in the `in-app purchase` section for my app:

> An In-App Purchase has been returned and is highlighted in the table
>   below

All of  the `in-app purchases` for a new app have been rejected.  They all show a status of **Developer Action Needed**. Going to each individual `in-app purchase` shows an exclamation sign with:

> Your In-App Purchase has been returned. You must modify or delete
>   the highlighted item.

However, it there's no explanation at all of what the error is. This seems to be a problem a lot of developers have just started seeing:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/78997#78997

Any ideas what's causing this? Is it just another `iTunes Connect` bug?

Comment: I don't seems to find any highlighted error in my in-app purchase products. So I am contacting Apple Support.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Seems like it's not a problem at all. It happens when your app is rejected. When you upload a new build you can add those IAPs again. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem, following is the screenshot of how my in-app purchase's details page did show a yellow highlighted portion:
[image: in-app purchase details]

What I did is: added another language.. then deleted the previous rejected language, then added the previously rejected-then-deleted language and then deleted the second added language. :-) And it worked!

Comment: Good answer. This resolved the problem for me. @Nay - if this works for you, please accept it.

Comment: Apple needs to to fix this nonsense.

Comment: @Chandni It maybe possible that you may not have understood the intermingled sentence above, it's tricky. Or it may have been possible that Apple has changed something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I modified the price of my in-app purchases which caused the validation errors with the language. I worked around this by modifying the in-app purchase description, saving, then putting it back to what it originally was.

Answer (score 17):

There is some issue with your binary or metadata that caused app review to reject your app. You need to address that issue. AND: Rather than reject the IAP, app review 'returned' it.  If they had rejected it you would have needed to recode a new IAP because once rejected an IAP can't be resubmitted. Once you address the reason the app was rejected, all you need do is open the IAP, add a " " to any field, save it, remove the " ", save it again and it will be ready. I do not recall if you also need to attach it to the new binary or whether it remains attached.

[Similar issue](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24993)

Comment: This worked but it should be pointed out that you can't save until you add a space (" ") between existing words or letters, you can't just append a space. You only need to do this in one of the fields but for each localisation.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, I edited >App Store Information >Subscription Display Name, saved the change, then immediately reverted my changes!