# Cannot re-add In-App Purchase to app after rejection in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I created an auto-renewable In-App Purchase (IAP) and added it to an app in iTunesConnect (ITC). The app got rejected because of missing information for the end user in the binary and the AppStore metadata (I had to explain how much it costs, that it is auto-renewing etc.). So I added the missing info to the app and metadata ...

### tl;dr

... but now I no longer can add the existing IAP to the app version in ITC.

---

### Detailed Walkthrough

... which (hopefully) fixed the issues, then I removed the old build (which cleared the error state of the app version) and instead added the fixed build. The IAP in the "Features" tab still had a red flag on it; I fixed this by following [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38255049). I dug further into the belly of the beast and found the the IAP group's name also had a red marker next to it. This time I followed [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38412685) and got rid of that error as well.

The IAP status is now "Waiting for Review", which I don't fully understand as I cannot send the IAP into review on its own (or can I?). When going back to the app version page I no longer can add the IAP to the version (as depicted in the first screenshot of [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH5-SW1)).

What should I do now?

- Delete the IAP and create a new one?
- Delete the whole app and create a new one?
- Just submit the app and hope that the IAP will still be available, even though it's not shown in the app version's details?

---

**EDIT**

As already mentioned in the comments: my question is *not a duplicate* of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677857). There, the solution is to add the IAP to the 
"In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page".

I am well aware that this would be the solution. However, the whole point of my question is that this very section is not available to me. I already have performed all the mentioned steps before, but after getting the app rejected once this section vanished and thus I cannot add the IAP anymore.

It looks like ITC considers my (single) IAP invalid and thus doesn't allow me to select it... and so for ITC there's no reason to even show the UI for adding an IAP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone : In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677857/iphone-in-app-purchases-must-be-submitted-with-a-new-app-version)

Comment: @GIJOW thx, I already read that question... but it's a different issue. I wish I had the mentioned "In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page", but as I described in my question: I do not get this section anymore and thus cannot add the IAP. It looks like ITC considers my (single) IAP invalid and thus doesn't allow me to select it anymore.

Comment: I think you can resubmit your app since your IAP is Waiting for Review. I had a similar problem and I did it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give it a shot... fingers crossed :)

Comment: @dr_barto faced the same issue. Does resubmit works without adding the InApp Purchase product? As it was already in "Waiting For Review" state.

Comment: @Soumen it worked for me... good luck if you try it too!

Comment: @dr_barto I have exactly the same problem as yours. As you said in your last comment, I just uploaded the new version without adding the new IAP again. (because I just *cannot*). Let's see the review results...

Comment: ... aaaaand... it was approved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that just re-submitting the same version works! Make sure the In App Purchase is in the "waiting for review" status again (maybe by editing the description).

Comment: That's the quintessence of the discussion in the comments on my question, but thanks for putting it in a proper answer anyway ;)